# window.location.href not working on my form

Tags: javascript, html, web

I create a web app that looks like this:

[image]

When i click the run model, i want that the form :"Dashbord", will open.

**The JS code**:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
function newDoc() {
    window.location.href("#http://127.0.0.1:8100/#dashboard");
}
}
</script>
```

When The "Run Model" button onClick activate the function: newDoc().

The problem is: that in my URL path it is written: http://127.0.0.1:8100/#dashboard
but the 'Dashboard' form is not logged. it stays in the same page.

What should i do?

Comment: you are missing a curly brace

Comment: Good spot @OliverWatkins - a good example of the importance of good indentation in your code

Comment: @OliverWatkins When i wrote the question in stackoverflow i missed the brace. It still not working...

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href` is not a method, it's a property.

Try assigning it instead (also note, I removed the leading `#` character)...

```
window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8100/#dashboard";
```

---

You also need to move your function outside of the `window.onload` event...

```
window.onload = function () {
}
function newDoc() {
    window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8100/#dashboard";
}
```

The `onload` event handler is generally only needed when you're dealing with specific elements on the page that won't be available until the page has finished loading.

By putting the `newDoc` within the `onload` event, you were effectively hiding it from being used directly by other events.

Comment: Check your braces (as Oliver said in his comment under your question)... the code in your question is missing a closing one `}`

Comment: When i wrote the question in stackoverflow i missed the brace. It still not working...

Comment: Why do you have the function in the `window.onload` handler?  You only need `onload` handlers when you need all the elements on the page to have loaded.  If you have a function that will be called at some other point move it outside of the `onload`

Comment: I will stop trying to help if you keep putting "still not working"... it is the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting console errors in your browser developer tools? Help us to help you